# JAVA Tree Sorting lexicographic

Tags: java, sorting, tree

I have a task to implement checking if two undirected graphs are isomorphic. For implementing tree I'm using simple adjacency list example http://theoryofprogramming.com/adjacency-list-in-java/. The second thing i need to do is sort tree "lexicographic" is there a difference between lexicographic sort and radix sort, when sorting adjacency list of a tree ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing terminology.

[Radix sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) is a sorting algorithm.

[Lexical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) is a mathematical generalization of "dictionary" order.

As far as I am aware, there is no such thing as "lexigographic sorting" ... unless this is your personal short-hand for sorting into a lexicographical order.

The relationship between a sorting algorithm and an order / ordering is that you use a sort algorithm to sort a "collection" of values into a particular order. The difference between them is ... like "comparing chalk and cheese".

---

However, based on how I think you intend to use them, you could sensibly use radix sort *with* a lexical order / ordering to sort an adjacency list.

Answer (score 0):

As from you question **lexicographic sort and radix sort** differences are-

**Radix Sort** is a linear sorting algorithm that sorts elements by processing them digit by digit.

```
for example to sort array [ 110,22,31 ]  using Redix Sort -  

So first we will arrange based on unit place-
[110,31,22]
Then we arrange based on 10th place-
[110,22,31]
Then we arrange based on 100th place-
[22,31,110]

Finally we have the sorted result [22,31,110].
```

**lexicographical Sort** is basically a dictionary order or we can say a generalization of the alphabetical order.

```
for example if we want to sort the below array-
[10,2,10001,1011,25,20001]

so the lexical sort will look like-
[10,10001,1011,2,20001,25]
```

Second thing you want to sort lexicographically using tree

So here we can use a **binary search tree** for that,
I am share a code for that hope it is helpful.

```
public class Node {
    private int value;
   private Node left, right;

    public Node(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        left = right = null;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Node getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(Node left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public Node getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(Node right) {
        this.right = right;
    }
}

public class TreeSort {

    // Root of BST
    private Node root;

    public Node getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void insert(int value)
    {
        root = insertRecursion(root, value);
    }

    private Node insertRecursion(Node root, int value)
    {

        /* If the tree is empty, return a new node */
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = new Node(value);
            return root;
        }

        /* Otherwise, recur down the tree */
        if (lexicographicalSort(value ,root.getValue())<0)
            root.setLeft(insertRecursion(root.getLeft(), value));

        else if (lexicographicalSort(value , root.getValue())>0)
            root.setRight( insertRecursion(root.getRight(), value));

        /* return the root */
        return root;
    }

    public void inorderRecursion(Node root)
    {
        if (root != null)
        {
            inorderRecursion(root.getLeft());
            System.out.print(root.getValue() + " ");
            inorderRecursion(root.getRight());
        }
    }

    public void treeInsertions(int[] arr)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            insert(arr[i]);
        }

    }

    private static int lexicographicalSort(long input1, long input2){

        // -ve means input1 is smaller
        //  +ve means input1 is larger
        //  0 means input1 and input2 are same
        long inp1 = input1;
        long inp2 = input2;
        int input1Length = 1;
        int input2Length = 1;

        while(inp1/10>0){
            input1Length++;
            inp1 = inp1/10;
        }

        while(inp2/10>0){
            input2Length++;
            inp2 = inp2/10;
        }

        int[] inArr1 = new int[input1Length];
        int[] inArr2 = new int[input2Length];

        inp1 = input1;
        inp2 = input2;

        int min = Math.min(input1Length,input2Length);

        while(inp1/10>0){
            inArr1[--input1Length] = (int)inp1%10;
            inp1 = inp1/10;
        }
        inArr1[--input1Length] = (int)inp1;

        while(inp2/10>0){
            inArr2[--input2Length] = (int)inp2%10;
            inp2 = inp2/10;
        }
        inArr2[--input2Length] = (int)inp2;

        int k = 0;

        while(k<min){
            if( inArr1[k] != inArr2[k]){
                return inArr1[k]-inArr2[k];
            }
            k++;
        }

        return inArr1.length-inArr2.length;
    }
}
```

Testing same-->

```
public class SolTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       // int arr[] = {5, 4, 7, 2, 11};
        int arr[] = {101,2,10,1012,8};
        TreeSort tree = new TreeSort();
        tree.treeInsertions(arr);
        tree.inorderRec(tree.getRoot());
}
}
```

**output**->10 101 1012 2 8

**Note**-> Instead of printing the result you can also store the same in List

And if you want a custom lexicographicalSort for String then use below method

```
 private static int lexicographicalSort(String input1, String input2){

        // -1 means input1 is smaller
        //  1 means input1 is larger
        //  0 means input1 and input2 are same
        char[] chArr1 = input1.toCharArray();
        char[] chArr2 = input2.toCharArray();
        int min = Math.min(chArr1.length,chArr2.length);
        int k = 0;

        while(k<min){
            if( chArr1[k] != chArr2[k]){
                return chArr1[k]-chArr2[k];
            }
            k++;
        }

        return chArr1.length-chArr2.length;
    }
```